# How to do parsing Gson to json fron google API?

Tags: android, gson

I started studying the Gson library, I try to do a lot of things about parsing. this is my code and I very appreciate it if someone tell me what I need to do to parsing Gson, this is my code:

```
package com.trip.android.trip.model;
```

import java.util.List;

public class TripPlaceDetails {

```
private Geometry geometry;
private String icon;
private String id;
private String name;
private OpeningHours openingHours;
private List<Photo> photos = null;
private String placeId;
private String reference;
private String scope;
private List<String> types = null;
private String vicinity;

public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}

public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public OpeningHours getOpeningHours() {
    return openingHours;
}

public void setOpeningHours(OpeningHours openingHours) {
    this.openingHours = openingHours;
}

public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
    this.photos = photos;
}

public String getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
}

public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getScope() {
    return scope;
}

public void setScope(String scope) {
    this.scope = scope;
}

public List<String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
    this.types = types;
}

public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}
```

}

This is my code gson from json:

```
public TripPlaceDetails getTripPlaceDetails(String jsonString) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TripPlaceDetails tripPlaceDetails = gson.fromJson(arr.get(i), TripPlaceDetails.class);
```

so now, what I should do after this code? I don't know what to do?

Thank for Help :)

Comment: "what I should do after this code?" -- how should we know? You have parsed the JSON, which is what you seem to want to do. It is up to you to use your `tripPlaceDetails` object somehow.

Comment: I do something like this but it's not ok..tripPlaceDetails.getOpeningHours().getOpenNow();

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it's not ok" means.

Comment: I need to get the details..

Comment: it's means that I need to get the details from google places API, and I do parsing' this parsing that I paste it's not give me the right details from google API.. so my parsing is not good..

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to parse Gson because it parses it for you. Just use returned object dot the properties. The names would exist in autocomplete.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);
// 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

Comment: you can give me example please?

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();

// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);

// 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);